# Java SQL date is off by 1 day

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date

I'm using a MySQL server which is located in the same timezone as me. Im trying to insert a java.util.Date into the database on a column of type `DATE` with the following code:

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
Date date = dateFormat.parse(map.value("date"));`

Where "date" is inserted. The problem is that the date is off by one day when looking in the database. Example: I inserted 2020-05-02, the database shows 2020-05-01. This gives the problem that when I want to get the matches with date 2020-05-02, I have to search for 1 day earlier which I dont want to do.
Also this happens between specific times on the day so im assuming its a timezone problem but I dont know how to fix it!

Tips?

Comment: Avoid `java.util.Date`; internally it is nothing more than a `long` which represents the number of milliseconds since January 1 1970 at midnight in UTC. It has long been supplanted by `LocalDateTime` in the `java.time` package. And when I need to insert now in the database, I would use `now()`

Comment: It may not solve your problem, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You are right, it’s a time zone problem for sure.

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type of your column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is coming from the MySQL Connector in java. Version 8.0.19 converts the date using the JVMs timezone which results in the 1 day off problem. This is resolved in the 8.0.20 patch. Read here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/

Comment: Good work on showing that bug fixed in their JDBC driver. Having been fixed, the approach I showed in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61563702/642706) should avoid further problems with time zone affecting your date.

Answer (score 4):

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, you should be using the MySQL type `DATE` when defining your column. This type matches the `DATE` type defined in the SQL standard.

On the Java side, never use `java.util.Date`. That class is part of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

For a date-only value in Java, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

In your map, you should be storing `LocalDate` object rather than mere string. But if you must, you can parse and generate strings. The format of your strings appear to coincide with the standard format defined in ISO 8601. The *java.time* classes use those standard formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2021-01-23" ) ;
```

Objects of the *java.time* classes can be exchanged with your database by using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) and later.

Write that to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Using the approach shown above makes time zones irrelevant: `LocalDate` via JDBC 4.2 or later on a column of type MySQL `DATE` — That is, unless your [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) is [buggy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-20.html) (Bug #30877755): See [Answer by Teh Swish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595617/642706).

Comment: I did what you said but it still shows one day before in the database. When I pass the date to the database and also get it back to my application, it shows the right date. I'm using activejdbc for the database transactions if that matters. I could add one day in my code to compensate for this but I dont feel thats viable...

Comment: I fixed it for now by adding one day when inserting and also one day when getting. Seems to work for now atleast.

Comment: @TehSwish I will ask a second time: *Exactly* what is the data type of your column?

Comment: The type is DATE