# Date values retrieved from database are showing previous day value using java.util.date

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

I have this weird phenomenon going in my code. I am using spring data jpa and MySQL database. I have a table named 'Submission' which has date field named 'finishedAt'. The datatype of that field is: 'Date'.

I have a mapped in class in Java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Submission")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Submission{
     //All the fields here

     @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
     java.util.Date finishedAtValue 
}
```

There is one method which tries to access this date value. When I print the date I see a value of previous day.

Example:

Lets say the date value in database is 2020-06-05 (yyyy-mm-dd)

The code snippet in the method is as follows:

```
//Code to get the entity from database successfully - submission

log.info("DateTimeAnswer retrieved from database: "+submission.getFinishedAtValue);
/*Expected date value from above log: 2020-06-05
Actual date value from above log: 2020-06-04*/
```

Not able to understand why this inconsistency while extracting this date value. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The most likely cause is a mismatch between the time zone in your application and the session time zone used by the database. MySQL has a number of date bugs too. What is the time zone in the database, client, and session? In your application, log the result of `TimeZone.getDefault()`, and the result of `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone` using the JPA database connection.

Comment: See also the release notes for the newest MySQL Connector/J driver, which fixed a bug in `Date` handling: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-20.html

Comment: database time zone and app time zone are different. SELECT @@global.time_zone returns +03.00 and TimeZone.getDefault() returns sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Denver"]

Comment: But what about `@@session.time_zone`?

Comment: It returns +03.00.

Comment: See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61595617/642706) with link to bug report on the faulty JDBC driver, *MySQL Connector*. Update to version 8.0.20 or later.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` class getter method returns the index for the day. This is `Date` class behavior.

Issue seems more or less related to `TimeZone` difference.

Please try the answers from similar question below.

Similar Question : [SimilarQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300047/jpa-temporaltype-date-giving-wrong-date/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I have date in database as: 2020-06-01 it logs the date value as 2020-05-31.

Comment: I've added link to similar question which will help you understanding it better way . It seems more or less related to timezone difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Check the time portion of the date before storing it and after retrieving it. I'm guessing this is due to [a bug in the MySQL driver prior to 8.0.20.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-20.html) If the date 2020-06-05 is treated as midnight +03:00, then converted to -06:00, it would be 6 PM on June 4, Mountain daylight time.