# Incorrect user date input being stored in MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timezone

I am developing a web application using jsp, java servlets and mysql. I am facing certain issue described below:
The user input date received from jsp page to servlet is correct as I can check in print statement but when sql statement is run in the servlet, the final date stored in the mysql table is incorrect, that too it is 1 day shifted before. For example, if selected input date is 2023-06-20 and the sqlDate variable is also containing the same format date (which I tried printing just before inserting into database table), now after executing insert/update statement , the value stored in the actual date column of the database is 2023-06-19, i.e one day less.

I have tried implementing various timezone settings suggested by chatGpt but none of them is working. My database server time zone is SYSTEM. I am also storing current timestamp in the table on updating the date field but somehow the timestamp shows correct date and time but only date field is getting incorrectly stored.

Following is few of my code lines. Please ignore any syntax errors as I have manually typed code lines in here.

```
**//user jsp form**
...
<input type="date" id ="start_date" name="start_date" value="here dynamically fetched date from the course_progress table is shown, which user can change and submit to update">
<!-- user selected date: 2023-06-20>
...
**//servlet class**
String date_start = request.getParameter("start_date");
java.sql.Date start_date = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
if(date_start !=null && !(date_start.isEmpty())){
try{
start_date = (java.sql.Date) new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse(request.getParameter("start_date")).getTime());
}catch(ParseException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
Course theCourse = new Course(few parameters, start_date);
System.out.println("Before sending Params are " + theCourse.toString()) // start_date: 2023-06-20
Messsage msg = dbUtil(theCourse);

**//dbUtil class**
...
java.sql.Date start_date = theCourse.getStart_date();
//System.out.println("Received Date in dbUtil is" + start_date ) // start_date: 2023-06-20

//get db connection
...
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

conn = dataSource.getConnection();
String sql = "update course_progress set start_date = ?, lecture_count = ? where course_id = ?";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1,start_date );
...
stmt.execute();
...
```

Please note that I am using java.sql.Date throughout my java entity  classes in the project, so I  cannot use java util date as it throws other conversion errors. Also, the type of start_date field in mysql table is **DATE**.

**EDIT:**
I think issue is with timezone difference since I tried inserting a date input into the table like below:

**stmt.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf("2023-07-19"));**

and the date inserted in the mysql table was again 1 day less, i.e 2023-07-18. My database server time zone is SYSTEM and current timestamp in the table shows correct date and time but only user input date processed through PreparedStatement in servlet is incorrectly stored.

I used the **TimeZone.getDefault()** method to retrieve the default time zone of the Java virtual machine (JVM)

```
// Get the system's time zone
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();

    // Get the offset value of the time zone
    int offsetHours = timeZone.getRawOffset() / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    int offsetMinutes = (Math.abs(timeZone.getRawOffset()) / (60 * 1000)) % 60;
    String offset = String.format("%+03d:%02d", offsetHours, offsetMinutes);


conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.createStatement().execute("SET time_zone = '" + offset + "'");
```

I got this solution from chatGPT, not sure what it does as I am new to JAVA .Please correct me what I am doing wrong

Comment: `I have tried implementing various timezone settings` where?

Comment: In servlet code

Comment: It is not available.

Comment: Are you sure that the web client and the database server are in the same timezone?

Comment: I think issue is with timezone difference since I tried inserting a date input into the table like below:

Comment: @user2773289 , I think issue is with timezone difference since I tried inserting a date input into the table like below: stmt.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf("2023-07-19")); and the date inserted in the mysql table was again 1 day less, i.e 2023-07-18. My database server time zone is SYSTEM and current timestamp in the table shows correct date and time but only user input date processed through PreparedStatement in servlet is incorrectly stored

Comment: @bearbear please read the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561247/java-sql-date-is-off-by-1-day

It may help...